# How is Plotly Surface Chart Data Mapped?

Tags: javascript, node.js, plotly

In [this youtube](https://youtu.be/9maEpZrfSdk?t=134) the presenter creates a nested 10X10 array of random number like this:

```
var arr = []
for (let i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    arr.push(Array.fill(10).map(()=>Math.random()));    
}
```

So effectively we have ten random numbers per nested array `[[0.23423, 0.23423, ...,0.235423]]`.

How does plotly plot this within the 3d surface plot.  I was thinking something like an array of objects with x,y,z coordinates would make more intuitive sense.  So `[{x:10, y:22, z:3453}, ...]`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not specified, the x and y axis are indexed with ascending integers. The nested array in this case has the `z` values, think of it as a matrix where `arr[x][y]` gives you the `z` value of the point `(x, y)`.

You can input the values of `x` and `y` axes as one dimensional arrays inside `newPlot` just like the `z` values are passed, the only difference is that `arr[i][j]` will give you the `z` value of the point `(x[i], y[j])`.

Comment: So for the first nested array would that correspond to x=[1....10], y=1 .....second nested array x=[1...10], y=2, ... and so on?  Or is it the reverse where we have x=1, y=[1...10], and for each y value there is a z value?

Comment: to my understanding is the second option, as `arr[x]` should give you all of the `y`s for that value of `x`.